# Communication between different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extension, toolbar

I am developing and extension for different browsers. In this extension user saves his data (say username and password) after that I want this extension to share its data with extension on other browser directly (without internet sync). Please guide me how can i achieve this. 
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Write to a file local to the machine known to all the extensions, e.g. on Windows: `%APPLICATION_DATA%/my-extension/database.db`; on Linux: `~/.my-extension/database.db`; and so on.

Comment: How is it possible to read and write to the aforementioned location ?

Comment: I don't know specifically. Some browsers might enforce sandboxes in their scripting languages (e.g. XUL). I do know that e.g. Flash can write to local file systems, so it must be possible somehow.  Note I am not advocating this as a good idea.

Comment: LOL - when you give an answer, please, do know specifically that what you are suggesting is doable (and document what requirements there are, e.g. using Flash).

Comment: I do know it's possible. Flash does it. Java does it. Heaps of malware do it. Ergo, any sufficiently motivated 3rd party can do it.

Comment: Indeed, but saying `Yeah, just save to a file and read from it` is **veeery** different from saying `Yeah, you need to use Flash or Java to write and read to an arbitrary file on the user's filesystem - but that might introduce security risks and unnecessary overhead`.